# Installation fails after period of time

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, Ultimate.

I'm running into a problem where, if my computer is on long enough, I am unable to install any software.

For example, if I reboot and try to install something, for the most part, it will succeed.

if I try and install something after a few hours/days, it will always fail.  Sometimes stating that "a previous install failed..." or "an install is already taking place..."  even though there is nothing being installed.

This also seems to be making my Windows updates fail at a pretty regular rate.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's windows, what did you expect? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are completing the previous install correctly?

It sounds like you're not rebooting when the installation program (or Windows Update) recommends it. If you don't then the installation will be left marked as incomplete - hence the error messages you report when you try to install something else.

I know it's a pain, but if the installation recommends a reboot you should follow the instruction.

Comment: Hmmm, never thought of that, because I usually do restart when it yells at me too.

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking!